# A Multitude Of Mates In 5-An Original Chess Puzzle

Tags: no-computers, chess

Here’s a toughie for you-and no computers allowed!

I have created this unique chess puzzle which white mates black in many different ways, all in 5 moves, no matter what black does. Options do exist for both sides.

Basically, black is trying to prolong their life as much as possible. But no matter what move they make (not like there’s a ton if options after the first 2 moves), they shall always be mated in 5 moves.

And yes, the position is legal.

EDIT: It’s come to my attention that there is much more than 9 mates in one. In this light, just find as as you can.

**White To Play And Checkmate Black In 5 Moves In Many Different Ways**

[image]

Good luck solving!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adding another:

> 1. a8=N+ Qxa8
>  2. Kxa8 Ba6
>  3. Qb8 Kb5
>  4. Ka7 b6
>  5. Qxb6#

2nd one is:

> 1. a8=N+ Qxa8
>  2. Kxa8 Ba6
>  3. Qb8 Kb5
>  4. c8=N b6
>  5. Qxb6#

Further adding:

> I think you can do a8= Q or R for the first move and still mate in 5. So, that must be another 8 such mates from the ones we have achieved with a Knight promotion.

Comment: I don't think a8=R works because black can play Qa7+.

Answer (score 4):

> 1. a8=N+ Qxa8+
>  2. Kxa8 Ba6 (Ka6 Qxb7#)
>  3. Qd8 Kb5
>  4. c8=N b6
>  5. Qxb6#
>
>  3... Bb5
>  4. c8=N+ Ka6
>  5. Qb6#

Comment: There's a pawn on c7 after the 2nd move, no? How do you get 3. Qc7?

Comment: @Sid D'oh, you're right. That didn't work.

Comment: Mate in 2 as well.

Answer (score 1):

Now that an answer has arisen, here my formal solution of all **39** different mates in five. You weren’t expected to find them all. The = signs indicate the type of promotion made by the pawn promotion on white’s first move. The annotations Qb8, Qd8, Qd7, and Kb8 that are by themselves indicate white’s third key move as a manner of organization.

> ```
>  Qd8
>  
>  1. a8=R Qxa8+ 2. Kxa8 Ba6 3. Qd8 Bb5 4. c8=N+ Ka6 5. Qb6#
>  1. a8=R Qxa8+ 2. Kxa8 Ba6 3. Qd8 Bb5 4. c8=Q+ Ka6 5. Qxb7#
>  1. a8=R Qxa8+ 2. Kxa8 Ba6 3. Qd8 Bb5 4. c8=B+ Ka6 5. Bxb7#
>  1. a8=R Qxa8+ 2. Kxa8 Ba6 3. Qd8 Kb5 4. c8=N b6 5. Na7#
>  1. a8=R Qxa8+ 2. Kxa8 Ba6 3. Qd8 Kb5 4. c8=N b6 5. Nd6#
>  1. a8=R Qxa8+ 2. Kxa8 Ba6 3. Qd8 Kb5 4. c8=N b6 5. Qxb6#
>  
>  =Q
>  
>  1. a8=Q Qxa8+ 2. Kxa8 Ba6 3. Qd8 Bb5 4. c8=N+ Ka6 5. Qb6#
>  1. a8=Q Qxa8+ 2. Kxa8 Ba6 3. Qd8 Bb5 4. c8=Q+ Ka6 5. Qxb7#
>  1. a8=Q Qxa8+ 2. Kxa8 Ba6 3. Qd8 Bb5 4. c8=B+ Ka6 5. Bxb7#
>  1. a8=Q Qxa8+ 2. Kxa8 Ba6 3. Qd8 Kb5 4. c8=N b6 5. Na7#
>  1. a8=Q Qxa8+ 2. Kxa8 Ba6 3. Qd8 Kb5 4. c8=N b6 5. Nd6#
>  1. a8=Q Qxa8+ 2. Kxa8 Ba6 3. Qd8 Kb5 4. c8=N b6 5. Qxb6#
>  
>  =N
>  
>  1. a8=N+ Qxa8+ 2. Kxa8 Ba6 3. Qd8 Bb5 4. c8=N+ Ka6 5. Qb6#
>  1. a8=N+ Qxa8+ 2. Kxa8 Ba6 3. Qd8 Bb5 4. c8=Q+ Ka6 5. Qxb7#
>  1. a8=N+ Qxa8+ 2. Kxa8 Ba6 3. Qd8 Bb5 4. c8=B+ Ka6 5. Bxb7#
>  1. a8=N+ Qxa8+ 2. Kxa8 Ba6 3. Qd8 Kb5 4. c8=N b6 5. Na7#
>  1. a8=N+ Qxa8+ 2. Kxa8 Ba6 3. Qd8 Kb5 4. c8=N b6 5. Nd6#
>  1. a8=N+ Qxa8+ 2. Kxa8 Ba6 3. Qd8 Kb5 4. c8=N b6 5. Qxb6#
>  
>  Qd7
>  
>  =Q
>  
>  1. a8=Q Qxa8+ 2. Kxa8 Ba6 3. Qd7 Kb5 4. c8=N b6 5. Na7#
>  1. a8=Q Qxa8+ 2. Kxa8 Ba6 3. Qd7 Kb5 4. c8=N b6 5. Nd6#
>  
>  =R
>  
>  1. a8=R Qxa8+ 2. Kxa8 Ba6 3. Qd7 Kb5 4. c8=N b6 5. Na7#
>  1. a8=R Qxa8+ 2. Kxa8 Ba6 3. Qd7 Kb5 4. c8=N b6 5. Nd6#
>  
>  =N
>  
>  1. a8=N+ Qxa8+ 2. Kxa8 Ba6 3. Qd7 Kb5 4. c8=N b6 5. Nd6#
>  1. a8=N+ Qxa8+ 2. Kxa8 Ba6 3. Qd7 Kb5 4. c8=N b6 5. Na7#
>  
>  Kb8
>  
>  =R
>  
>  1. a8=R Qxa8+ 2. Kxa8 Ba6 3. Kb8 Kb5 4. Ka7 b6 5. Qxa6#
>  
>  =Q
>  
>  1. a8=Q Qxa8+ 2. Kxa8 Ba6 3. Kb8 Kb5 4. Ka7 b6 5. Qxa6#
>  
>  =N
>  
>  1. a8=N+ Qxa8+ 2. Kxa8 Ba6 3. Kb8 Kb5 4. Ka7 b6 5. Qxa6#
>  
>  Qb8
>  
>  =Q
>  
>  1. a8=Q Qxa8+ 2. Kxa8 Ba6 3. Qb8 Kb5 4. Ka7 b6 5. Qxb6#
>  1. a8=Q Qxa8+ 2. Kxa8 Ba6 3. Qb8 Kb5 4. c8=N b6 5. Na7#
>  1. a8=Q Qxa8+ 2. Kxa8 Ba6 3. Qb8 Kb5 4. c8=N b6 5. Nd6#
>  1. a8=Q Qxa8+ 2. Kxa8 Ba6 3. Qb8 Kb5 4. c8=N b6 5. Qxb6#
>  
>  =R
>  
>  1. a8=R Qxa8+ 2. Kxa8 Ba6 3. Qb8 Kb5 4. Ka7 b6 5. Qxb6#
>  1. a8=R Qxa8+ 2. Kxa8 Ba6 3. Qb8 Kb5 4. c8=N b6 5. Na7#
>  1. a8=R Qxa8+ 2. Kxa8 Ba6 3. Qb8 Kb5 4. c8=N b6 5. Nd6#
>  1. a8=R Qxa8+ 2. Kxa8 Ba6 3. Qb8 Kb5 4. c8=N b6 5. Qxb6#
>  
>  =N
>  
>  1. a8=N+ Qxa8+ 2. Kxa8 Ba6 3. Qb8 Kb5 4. Ka7 b6 5. Qxb6#
>  1. a8=N+ Qxa8+ 2. Kxa8 Ba6 3. Qb8 Kb5 4. c8=N b6 5. Na7#
>  1. a8=N+ Qxa8+ 2. Kxa8 Ba6 3. Qb8 Kb5 4. c8=N b6 5. Nd6#
>  1. a8=N+ Qxa8+ 2. Kxa8 Ba6 3. Qb8 Kb5 4. c8=N b6 5. Qxb6#
> ```